# PDO fails when using "WHERE" in a query

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo, silex

I am using `PHP`, `Silex`, and a `PostgreSQL` database. I have a piece of code that executes exactly as expected:

```
$statement = $app['pdo']->query("SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 50"); 
$string = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($string);
return $json;
```

When I change one thing by adding a "`WHERE`" parameter, it fails:

```
$statement = $app['pdo']->query("SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 50 WHERE id > 3000"); 
$string = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($string);
return $json;
```

I checked that "id" is not capitalized in the schema and it is formatted as an integer. Id values in the table range from 1 to 5000, and it is populated with random entries, many of which should satisfy the query.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WHERE comes first

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id > 3000 LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Wow. I wish error reporting would have told me that.

Answer (score 2):

Limit goes after the where clause

```
$statement = $app['pdo']->query("SELECT * FROM my_tableWHERE id > 3000  LIMIT 50");
```